# Retrieving all FDF fields crashes server

Tags: php, fdf

I want to retrieve all fields from a fdf file, which i generated with pdftk. Unfortunately the example provided on the php website makes apache crash...

I have this:

```
$infdf = fdf_open($fdf_file);
for ($field = fdf_next_field_name($infdf); $field != ""; $field = fdf_next_field_name($infdf, $field))
{
    echo "field: $field\n";
}
fdf_close($infdf);
```

Any suggestions for the cause of the crash?

Thanks!

Comment: If apache is crashing, it's a bug in the PHP module running inside apache.  Nothing you can do about it in your PHP file.

Comment: Indeed, also the pdftk is generating a bad output file